# pgAdmin 4 not returning rows when I do a join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am practicing my SQL using the book "SQL For Mere Mortals." I am now at the section of the book where I am doing joins.

When I do a join, I either get a message stating "0 rows affected" or way fewer rows than I should (11 rows from my query, when the answer says I should be getting 200 rows) and no error messages. I checked my queries against the answers and even ran the answer query but still get the "0 rows affected" message.

Here is what I am running:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
Concat(Employees.EmpFirstName, ' ', Employees.EmpLastName) AS EmpFullName, 
Concat(Customers.CustFirstName, ' ', Customers.CustLastName) AS CustFullName
FROM (Employees INNER JOIN Orders ON (Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID)) 
INNER JOIN Customers ON (Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID);
```

It results in 0 rows.

When running the answer view

```sql
SELECT empfullname, custfullname
    FROM salesordersexample.ch08_employees_and_customers;
```

it returns 211 rows

The code for the answer view is as follows:

```sql
CREATE VIEW CH08_Employees_And_Customers
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
Concat(Employees.EmpFirstName,' ', Employees.EmpLastName) AS EmpFullName,
Concat(Customers.CustFirstName, ' ', Customers.CustLastName) AS CustFullName
FROM (Employees INNER JOIN Orders ON (Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID)) 
INNER JOIN Customers ON (Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID);
```

Has anyone encountered an issue like this or spot something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is the question asking for?

One suggestion I would make is to remove the extraneous parentheses. To be honest, I'm not sure how Postgres handles those extra parentheses around the table names. So for example, from clause would be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Employees
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
```

One thing to keep in mind about an INNER JOIN is that it will remove any rows where there is not a match. So for example, any employee will be excluded if they do not appear on an order, and in a similar vein any order will be excluded if there is not a matching customer record.

If the question is asking for the distinct employee and customer name combinations for every order where there is an employee and customer listed for that order, then in theory that query should work (although I might suggest starting with the Orders table in the FROM clause, since that is a bit easier to follow). I would say give removing the parentheses a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Have never used those braces like this before . But try this

```html
SELECT DISTINCT 
Concat(Employees.EmpFirstName, ' ', Employees.EmpLastName) AS EmpFullName, 
Concat(Customers.CustFirstName, ' ', Customers.CustLastName) AS CustFullName
FROM Employees 
INNER JOIN Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID;
```